# OpenGL 4.5 glNamedFunction not found

Tags: c++, opengl, linker

It seems that my linker does not find the new 4.5 functions:

```
undefined reference to `glNamedBufferData'
```

Though when I do a `glxinfo | grep version` I get:

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.18
```

though, only with `optirun` ...

I compile with `-DGL_GL_EXT_PROTOTYPES` and link with `-glfw -lGL -lpng`

What could I miss?

Here is a minimal (EDITED) code example:

```
#include "glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    if(!glfwInit()) return 64;
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600, "OpenGL Test", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 64;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        exit(66);
    }   
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    GLfloat data[] = {0,0, 0,1, 1,1, 1,0};
    glNamedBufferData(buffer, sizeof(data), data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GLint error = glGetError();
    printf("%d\n", error);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:
`g++ -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES main.cc glad.h glad.c -o test -ldl -lGL -lglfw`

I get Error 1282 after calling namedBuffers --- INVALID_OPERATION I think it is ...

EDIT:

So I used both `glew` as well as `glad` to get the extensions linked. The function calls now actually compile but any "named" function actually has no effect on the program --- buffers do not get provided with data or similar, though all the other functions still work as expected.

Comment: What OpenGL Loading library are you using? I don't see you #including special headers or using anything to actually load those entrypoints.

Comment: All functions I used till now never needed a loading library, so that might be the problem.

Comment: But aren't these functions core in 4.5? Using Archlinux I thought I will not need glew as everything is in the core profile ...

Comment: I think I have loaded the function with glew --- at least I don't get compile errors, but the function itself does not seem to do what it should --- it does not buffer the data ... I did not manage to find any code examples to use the glNamed[Functions] sadly